# how to check the battery percentage of Apple airpods and case on linux?

Tags: bluetooth, power-management, i3, battery

is there any command for checking AirPods battery status on Linux.
I am developer of [i3blocks-airpods](https://github.com/4khi1/i3blocks-airpods)
Just want to know if there is a way to check battery status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code from github https://github.com/delphiki/AirStatus .

```
git clone git@github.com:delphiki/AirStatus.git
cd AirStatus
pip3 install bleak
python3 main.py
```

You will see the following when using this:

```
{"status": 1, "charge": {"left": 90, "right": 90, "case": -1}, "charging": "N/A", "model": "AirPods", "date": "2021-09-21 12:30:30", "raw": "0719010f202b998f000005521019d293ae902e66fbc70XXXXXXXX"}
```